# Google VIS API library blocked

Tags: google-visualization

I'm currently developing an application on Cloudant servers. I'm using Google Vis API library. The file "jsapi.js" is installed on the Cloudant server, I am not loading from the web, but it seems that Google is trying to load something externally. Is there a way to overcome this?

> [blocked] The page at https://username.cloudant.com/web/_design/web/index.html ran insecure content from http://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1.0&packages=corechart%2Ctable.

Answer (score 6):

The jsapi.js file is for the Google loader, which pulls the Visualization API scripts from Google's servers.  Locally hosting the API is forbidden according to the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms) - you must access it live from Google.

Load the jsapi.js file like this to avoid the security problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately offline access is not authorized/possible. You can vote [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=277) and spread the word so that Google does something for that - still do not understand why Google does not want to publish offline versions from time to time.